# XMLHttpRequest() got denied when call http URL from cordova app

Tags: cordova, extjs, xmlhttprequest

I have cordova sencha app both in  windows and android ,I got denied when call http URL using XMLHttpRequest() on android sencha, but it run smoothly on windows

here is my code

```
var me = this,
        xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      


    this._errorCallback = errorCallback;
    this._xhReq = xhReq;
    xhReq.open("GET", source,true);

    if (options && options.headers && options.headers.Authorization) {
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Authorization", options.headers.Authorization);
    }

    xhReq.responseType = "blob";

    xhReq.onload = function () {
        if (xhReq.status === 200 || xhReq.status === 0) {
            
        } else {
            errorCallback();
        }
    };

    xhReq.onerror = function (e) {
        logger.error("XHR download error occurred.  status code = " + xhReq.status + " error msg = " + xhReq.statusText);
        errorCallback();
    };
    xhReq.ontimeout = function () {
        logger.error("XHR Timeout! status code = " + xhReq.status + " error msg = " + xhReq.statusText);
        errorCallback();
    };

    xhReq.send(null);
```

it always ended up in onerror because the http URL , it works when call https URL, does anyone knows how to force to work with http URL in android , thanks

Comment: If the request is failing, what error code you are getting?